# Proof of the statement based on measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory, random

Let $A, A' ⊂ 2 ^S$.

Prove that: If $A ⊂ A'$ , then $σ(A) ⊂ σ(A')$.

Comment: What did you try? Let's start from the beginning: what is the definition of the generated sigma algebra?

Comment: You've given what some Readers call a "bare problem statement" Question.  I'm happy to assume you are having difficulty with a proof, but simply imposing on Readers to "Prove that" without indicating what you tried will give the impression that your exercise is just being reassigned to them without any digestion on your part of the problem's meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Observe hat $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal A'\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal A')$ where $\sigma(\mathcal A')$ denotes a $\sigma$-algebra and then apply the definition of $\sigma(\mathcal A)$.